# Embed Livestream into Website (Without Available Embed Support)

Tags: javascript, html, stream, embed

I am trying to embed a streaming preview of Caffeine.tv into my website.

Caffeine.tv has no official embedding or at least not for what I know but moderators of the platform told me you can do it yourself I only have no clue how and hope people here would be able to give me a hand in that.

Normally you watch Caffeine.tv stream through for example https://www.caffeine.tv/Kaph which shows an image of the URL but no visible video.

There is a workaround for that which is watching over https://preview.caffeine.tv/kaph

This shows preview but no window in the link now what I would like to do is use the preview URL and embed that into my website.

I look forward to support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want can be achieved by using an [iframe](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) :)

```html
<iframe src="https://preview.caffeine.tv/kaph"></iframe>
```

Please note, the above may not load correctly depending on Stack Overflow's allowance of cross-origin content from iFrames.

Please see this working on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8y74fd5m/)

Comment: May thanks that fixes it, do you know of I can also make the https://caffeine.tv/Kaph as an example visible that when I link that with my own stream name on Twitter that people can see a preview of that running through the link?

Last one is there a way of resizing the window as its super small now.

Comment: Sure! You could do something like `<iframe src="https://preview.caffeine.tv/kaph" style="overflow:hidden;height:100%;width:100%" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>` to alter the height, or even just `<iframe src="https://preview.caffeine.tv/kaph"  height="500" width="500"></iframe>`

Comment: As for `do you know of I can also make the caffeine.tv/Kaph as an example visible that when I link that with my own stream name on Twitter that people can see a preview of that running through the link? ` I'm not sure what you mean by this, sorry

Comment: So basically if we take a link from Twitch and upload that to Twitter for example it shows a small live preview right?

If I do this with Caffeine it only shows an image but is there actually a way to make a preview be available that can be clicked as clicking the image does not work with Caffeine that just opens the image.

Comment: Hey maybe post this one in a new question with a bit of source code as an example & I can try to have a go at solving it for you. I'm not really seeing these results on my end when running my code, so best ask a new question with new source code so this can be solved by more than one mind :)